# How to render Html template with info from database in Services

Tags: grails

I am having dificulties to do the following:

- Having a job that runs from time to time (Done)
- Fetching some data from database inside that job (Done)
- Next step would be use that data with a template that I already created (HTML) and then render it to PDF
- Then send an email with that pdf in attachment

This is my current job:

```
def execute() {
       println("Hi, I am a schedule Job triggering every half an hour from 7 AM to 22 PM that will never stop running until master jose tells me to :)")

       EventService.updateOffersdwh()
       EventService.getUncheckedOffers()
    }
```

which is working properly :)

Those are my service's methods called in the previous job:

```
def updateOffersdwh(){

    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://"+hostname+":5432/xyz", username, password, "org.postgresql.Driver")
    sql.rows(" Select From bird_admin.updt_offerorders('2018-03-07','2018-03-07','" + database + "') ");

    println('Updating Order and Offers datawarehouse...');      
}

def getUncheckedOffers(){

    def sql = sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://"+hostname+":5432/xyz", username, password, "org.postgresql.Driver")

    def query = "select id, poo_id, b.name, b.address_line1, b.address_line2, b.zipcode, event_date::date, task_name, sku_id, sku_name, column_type, column_value, instance_name,checked FROM bird_admin.ooisdwh a LEFT JOIN sd_bel.cfg_point_of_operation b ON a.poo_id = b.id WHERE checked = false"
    def offers = sql.rows(query)

    println('DEBUG OFFERS FINAL:: '+offers)
}
```

Can anyone please advice or guide me on the next steps?

How can I use a template in html that I already have in my views\template folder?

What is the best way to use the info from the database and render the html with that info?

Should I use a controller? If so, how? I'm kinda lost now :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if you want to use the template for the body of the email or the attachment, but to use a template for the body of the email you can do the following.

First add the dependency for the [Grails mail plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/mail):

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Then in your service generate the body using the template and send like:

```
class YourService {

    def groovyPageRenderer
    def mailService


    def getUncheckedOffers(){

        def sql = sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://"+hostname+":5432/xyz", username, password, "org.postgresql.Driver")

        def query = "select id, poo_id, b.name, b.address_line1, b.address_line2, b.zipcode, event_date::date, task_name, sku_id, sku_name, column_type, column_value, instance_name,checked FROM bird_admin.ooisdwh a LEFT JOIN sd_bel.cfg_point_of_operation b ON a.poo_id = b.id WHERE checked = false"
        def offers = sql.rows(query)
        def content = groovyPageRenderer.render( view: "/aViewDirectory/mail",
                    model:[offers : offers ] )

        mailService.sendMail {
            to 'anEmailRecipient@somewhere.com'
            subject "Email subject"
            html( content )
    }
}
```

There's a section in the email plugin docs [about attachments](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.3%20Attachments).
You can follow the steps above to generate a PDF from a template and attach as per the docs.

Comment: This was what I was probably looking for. Thank you, alot @Mike W !!

Comment: Actually, do you know how to render the view to pdf and then add to attach?

Comment: Take a look at the rendering plugin, you just need to render to a file and attach to email, http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/rendering, this section should help http://gpc.github.io/rendering/guide/3.%20Rendering.html

Comment: I've a template that I made with html and bootstrap which I can't render into pdf, always throwing errors about tags not being closed, which doesn't make alot of sense. Is there a specific kind of  template I need to use? Seems like have something to do with xHTML, but I didn't got it right, i guess :D Thanks anyways, for your help!